# What is the difference between an artifact and a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent (we're both beginner players) casts a [Renegade Freighter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRenegade%20Freighter%5d), which is an Artifact — Vehicle. Can he attack me with it on his next turn? They are attacking me with it like it is a creature, but this doesn't seem right to me.

Also, it says "Crew 2", which, when enabled, turns it into an artifact creature. What is an artifact creature?

Comment: You're talking about Renegade *Freighter*, right?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Fixed.

Comment: I'd suggest downloading Magic Duels. It's free and provides an excellent tutorial for those just starting magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cards that are not creatures can't attack or block. That includes artifacts.

So even if a card has a power and toughness and an effect when it attacks, it can't attack or block if it isn't a creature.

An artifact creature is a creature that is also an artifact. These things can attack and block, because they are creatures. By default, the Renegade Freighter isn't an artifact creature. But once you activate the crew ability, it becomes an artifact creature instead of just an artifact until the end of turn. Then, if you controlled the card since the beginning of your upkeep (summoning sickness), you can attack with it.

Comment: Keep in mind that any card that refers to a creature can affect a Vehicle that has been crewed this turn (Murder, Unsummon, etc.). Once the turn is over and the Vehicle is no longer a creature, then those cards have no effect (see George Oscar Bluth's answer below). Conversely, any card that refers to an artifact will ALWAYS be able to apply to an artifact creature (unless it specifically says noncreature artifact). Finally, and this gets a little weird to imagine, a crewed Vehicle can, in fact, crew a second Vehicle.

Answer (score 7):

An artifact is simply a card type, like "land", "creature", "instant" etc. After you cast an artifact card, it just sits there on the battlefield and only does whatever its own text says it does.

A creature is also a type of card, but creatures are different than other card types in that they can attack and block.

An "artifact creature" is just an object that is both an artifact and a creature. So Renegade Freighter, as an artifact, cannot attack or block. But because it is also a vehicle, it has a "crew" ability that lets it become an artifact creature, so that you can attack and block with it.

Answer (score 5):

A Vehicle is a kind of object that becomes a creature when it is *crewed*: a number of creatures with total power not less than the crew cost are tapped, and the artifact vehicle is now an artifact creature until end of turn.

An artifact creature is just an object that is both an artifact and a creature. See the definitions of these objects for information on the implications.

If it has not been crewed, it is not a creature, and by rule 506.3, it cannot be used to attack.

Comment: Where can I find "the definition of these objects"? Any chance you can add them to your answer?

Comment: @splatteredbits In the comprehensive rules, but there aren't really concise definitions, just sets of rules that apply to each. Artifacts have a set of subtypes they can have (like equipment and vehicles), and there's not much else specific to artifacts (though there are detailed rules for specific subtypes of artifacts like equipment). Creatures also have subtypes (the zillions of creature types), and have power and toughness, can attack and block, are affected by "summoning sickness", and can have damage marked on them.

Comment: The upshot is, you already know how creatures work, and an artifact creature works the same way, it's just also an artifact.

Answer (score 2):

> My opponent (we're both beginner players) casts a Renegade Freighter,
>   which is an Artifact — Vehicle. Can he attack me with it on his next
>   turn?

Yes, if it's a creature. A creature can attack when it has been in play, under the same players control since the beginning of the turn (or if it has haste), even if it wasn't a creature previously.

---

> Also, it says "Crew 2", which, when enabled, turns it into an artifact
>   creature. What is an artifact creature?

Crew X is an ability, when activated adds creature to its types.

So the card by default reads:

> Card Name:
>   Renegade Freighter
>
> Types:
>   Artifact — Vehicle
>
> Card Text:
>   Whenever Renegade Freighter attacks, it gets +1/+1 and gains trample until end of turn.
>   Crew 2 (Tap any number of creatures you control with total power 2 or more: This Vehicle becomes an artifact creature until end of turn.)
>
> P/T:
>   4 / 3

After a player activates Crew 2 the card reads:

> Card Name:
>   Renegade Freighter
>
> Types:
>   Artifact — Vehicle **Creature**
>
> Card Text:
>   Whenever Renegade Freighter attacks, it gets +1/+1 and gains trample until end of turn.
>   Crew 2 (Tap any number of creatures you control with total power 2 or more: This Vehicle becomes an artifact creature until end of turn.)
>
> P/T:
>   4 / 3

This makes the card a creature, so if you have a card that says Kill Target Creature, you are now able to target Renegade Freighter.